# Android ProgressBar does not work unless the progress value and max value are the same

Tags: android, kotlin, android-progressbar

The xml code:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/meditationProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_progress_gray"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="3660"
    android:progress="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
    android:rotation="-90" />
```

I set android:max="3660" because that's the maximum value the progressbar will ever have.

Kotlin Code:

```
override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            meditationProgress++
            meditationProgressBar.progress=meditationTimeInSeconds-meditationProgress
            
        }
```

Variables:

```
private var meditationProgress = 0
private var meditationTimeInSeconds:Int = meditationTime*60
```

I actually tried replacing "meditationTimeInSeconds" by "30" in the onTick function and I changed the android:max of the ProgressBar to 30 and the progress bar actually worked but I have no idea why it isn't working now.

Edit 1:

```
private var meditationTimeInMilliSeconds = meditationTime*60000

 meditateTimer=object: CountDownTimer(meditationTimeInMilliSeconds.toLong(),1000){

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            meditationProgress++
            meditationProgressBar.progress=meditationTimeInSeconds-meditationProgress
            meditationTvTimer.text=(meditationTimeInSeconds-meditationProgress).toString()
        }
```

I actually tried not using the drawable i am using for the progressbar and it still doesn't work. Anyways, here's the code for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.7"
            android:thicknessRatio="50"
            android:useLevel="true">
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It's still the same. The progressbar doesn't work unless the progress value and the android:max value of the progressbar are the same

Comment: Have you tried logging the values? Maybe ``meditationTimeInSeconds - meditationProgress`` is more than you were expecting. When you hardcoded the value and it worked, did you try using ``3660`` instead of ``30``?

Comment: i did actually and it didn't work. the progressbar just doesn't move

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably because with a max of `3660`, your range is so large that small changes aren't really noticeable, especially if your display is only *100dp x 100dp*.

Assuming `3660` is seconds... actually let's call it 3600 to make the maths easier, it would take 10 seconds to move 1 degree around a circular progress bar, or 36 seconds to change a 100dp-tall one by 1 dp. You might be able to see the bar/gap appear when it first starts from empty/full, but it's going to be hard to see it *moving*.

Whereas if it's just a `30` second range, it'll move pretty quick and be obvious that it's working. I tested your code (without the custom drawable which I don't have, I just let it go vertical) and it works fine - it just takes a while to see progress when the full range is over an hour

---

edit: if it helps, here's my code that works:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    private val meditationTime = 31
    private var meditationProgress = 0
    private var meditationTimeInSeconds: Int = meditationTime * 60

    private lateinit var meditationProgressBar: ProgressBar

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        meditationProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.meditationProgressBar)
        
        object : CountDownTimer(meditationTimeInSeconds * 1000L, 1000L) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                meditationProgress++
                meditationProgressBar.progress = meditationTimeInSeconds - meditationProgress
                Log.d("TICK", "Progress: ${meditationProgress.toFloat() / meditationTimeInSeconds}")
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }.start()
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/meditationProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:max="3660"
        android:progress="100"
        android:rotation="-90" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of the progress bar after some time has passed]

Comment: The strange thing is that if i just use value like "120" then the progressbar still doesn't work. Not even when the value is 60. I wonder what actually is the problem here

Comment: i just set the max value and progress value both to 120 and it worked but why should i change the max value of the progressbar everytime to make it work? do you think there's a problem or is this how progressbar are supposed to work like?

Comment: It worked fine for me, even with 3660 as the max - with a small value it only filled up a small part. All I can say is I don't have your full code, so here's what I used: ``meditationTime = 61`` (so it works out as 3660 seconds) and the ``CountDownTimer`` was initialised with ``millisInFuture = meditationTimeInSeconds * 1000L`` and ``countDownInterval = 1000L``. And I didn't have your custom drawable, so I just took that line out - test it without that, see if it makes a difference for some reason. You have a bug somewhere, it's meant to work the way you're expecting to

Comment: I dunno what to tell you, I've added the code that's working for me, but it's basically the same as yours. Unless you're miscalculating something, I can't see why it would be any different. Can't do any more than that!

Comment: my code was actually giving different values to the progress like 60,120,180 and so on according to the user needs but the max value was 3660 all the time so what i did was that i set the maximum value like this `meditationProgressBar.max=meditationTimeInSeconds` and it's working fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and changed `meditateTimer=object: CountDownTimer(meditationTimeInMilliSeconds.toLong(),1000)` to `meditateTimer=object: CountDownTimer(meditationTimeInMilliSeconds.toLong(),200)` mean reduced countdown timer interval to see whether progress bar value is changing or not. Progress started from 1858 and decreasing by one after 200ms. After few seconds I saw that the progress bar is changing accordingly. So there is nothing wrong with progress bar the only thing is that the max progress value is large and there is very little change occur after 1000 ms delay in your code which is not easily detected by human eyes. You may wait for a long time to detect the changes.

Comment: so android:max=3660 and sometimes the counter is supposed to do just 60 seconds or 120 seconds countdown in the progressbar and i thought if i set the android:max=3660 then the progressbar will work perfectly fine for any value below 3660 but i just saw that the progressbar sets 3660 as a whole and just does the countdown with the time i give it and it starts at the last and yeah the change is very unnoticeable but yeah it's there. So i was wondering how I could make the progressbar work for any value below 3660? can i programatically change the max value of progressbar everytime?

Comment: Yes, you can change max value of a progressbar according to different tasks by using meditationProgressBar.max = 60 or meditationProgressBar.max = 120 before starting  count down timer. 60 and 120 are static values you need to calculate exact value each time you execute different tasks.

Comment: yes but is there a way i can assign a variable to the value of max so that it takes the value of that variable?

Comment: okay i did it programatically and it's working now ;)